# How to encrease font-size of Command Palette in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Does anybody know, how can I make larger font in Sublime Text 2 "floating" window / Command Palette?

[image]

Comment: It's called the command pallette. From a quick google search it looks like you need to create a custom theme.

Comment: Thanks for the right name :)  I searched a little, but I cant find the exact value for "command palette font-size" :( I don't want new theme, because I have more things custom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with upgrade to Sublime Text 3. I'll recommend this solution.